# How to run an async function in both IPython and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql, python-asyncio, gql

I have an async function that grabs some data from an external API using GraphQL:

```py
async def main():
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(
        url="https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql")

    async with Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True) as session:
        query = gql(
            """
            query getContinents {
              continents { code, name }
            }
        """
        )

        result = await session.execute(query)
        return result
```

I wish to call this function in my library in a way that is independent of whether it's being called from a notebook or a Python script.

If I call it with:

```py
print(asyncio.run(main()))
```

In my Python IDE it successfully prints the correct results.  However, running the same in a notebook results in:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c9c9ed9baa3b> in <module>
     20         result = await session.execute(query)
     21         return result
---> 22 print(asyncio.run(main()))
     23 
     24 # await main()

AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'
```

In the notebook, I can run:

```py
print(await main())
```

And it works perfectly there.  However I cannot run it in my script or I get:

```py
  File "main.py", line 23
    await main()
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

Is there a way I can write my module so that it works on both a Python interpreter and within IPython?

Comment: What happens if you try "asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete(main())"?

Comment: @FaustoAlonso `RuntimeError: no running event loop` when run in the Python IDE

Comment: I believe theres a missing `if __name__ == "__main__": asyncio.run(main())`. This will allow you to use the main as a script or as a module with the "await main()" directly in the notebook.

Comment: I think I see. So I should actually be leaving the decision of how to run the async code to the person calling the library.  That makes sense.  Thanks @FaustoAlonso